# Can I change the name of `nohup.out`?

Tags: bash, logging, nohup

When I run `nohup some_command &`, the output goes to `nohup.out`; `man nohup` says to look at `info nohup` which in turn says:

> If standard output is a terminal, the
>   command's standard output is appended
>   to the file 'nohup.out'; if that
>   cannot be written to, it is appended
>   to the file '$HOME/nohup.out'; and if
>   that cannot be written to, the command
>   is not run.

But if I already have one command using `nohup` with output going to `/nohup.out` and I want to run another, `nohup` command, can I redirect the output to `nohup2.out`?

Comment: do you know if the answers suggested also redirect the errors to the given location?

Comment: I've personally found more useful to do `nohup python script.py > my_output.out &`

Answer (score 527, accepted):

```
nohup some_command &> nohup2.out &
```

and voila.

---

Older syntax for Bash version < 4:

```
nohup some_command > nohup2.out 2>&1 &
```

Comment: @ismail, if I understand, this directs the output away from stdout and nohup.out, into nohup2.out. Then what does `2>&1&` do?

Comment: `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to the same output file as `stdout` which is in this case `nohup2.out`

Comment: In Bash 4, the two redirects can be abbreviated as one `&> nohup2.out`.

Comment: I tried &> nohup2.out and it works, but how can you tell your bash version?

Comment: I found that this redirect method always rewrite out file, not the standard append writing way. How to achieve redirect while not rewrite the out file?

Comment: With `GNU bash, version 4.3.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` the `&>>` version is not working for me. (on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`)

Comment: @VajkHermecz there is only one `>` so it is `&>`

Comment: @monkut Just typing `help` in bash also works. Or `help | grep version`. Easier to remember to me.

Comment: I think, what this does actually is not redirect the output of `nohup`, but the output of the `nohup`ped command. The result maybe not the same, as `nohup` creates the `nohup.out` anyway. It's just empty in this way.

Comment: @ismail, what is the need to add '&' at the end of the command? I see commands everywhere over the net where there is no ampersand at the end of the command. I am confused. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Djeah, I had the same question as to why there are both ampersands.  the `&>` operator redirects to stdout (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) and the second `&` just puts the job in the background, though you can also Ctrl+Z and bg and achieve that result.

Comment: when I do `nohup command > file.out 2>&1` it works, but it's not running in the background.  When I add the `&` at the end, it runs it the background, but I get no data recorded in file.out.  How do I fix this?

Comment: does this also re-direct stderr? I want to direct everything, whether it is an error or output to a single source.

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, file descriptor '2' is for stderr.

Answer (score 71):

For some reason, the above answer did not work for me; I did not return to the command prompt after running it as I expected with the trailing &. Instead, I simply tried with

```
nohup some_command > nohup2.out&
```

and it works just as I want it to. Leaving this here in case someone else is in the same situation. Running Bash 4.3.8 for reference.

Comment: does this also re-direct stderr? I want to direct everything, whether it is an error or output to a single source.

Answer (score 20):

Above methods will remove your output file data whenever you run above nohup command.

To **Append output in user defined file** you can use `>>` in nohup command.

```
nohup your_command >> filename.out &
```

This command will append all output in your file without removing old data.

Comment: does this also re-direct stderr? I want to direct everything, whether it is an error or output to a single source.

Answer (score 12):

As the file handlers points to i-nodes (which are stored independently from file names) on Linux/Unix systems You can rename the default `nohup.out` to any other filename any time after starting `nohup something&`. So also one could do the following:

```
$ nohup something&
$ mv nohup.out nohup2.out
$ nohup something2&
```

Now `something` adds lines to `nohup2.out` and `something2` to `nohup.out`.

Comment: does this also re-direct stderr? I want to direct everything, whether it is an error or output to a single source.

Comment: @CharlieParker Actually you can. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820616/redirect-nohups-stderr-to-nohup-out

Answer (score 1):

my **start.sh** file:

```
#/bin/bash

nohup forever -c php artisan your:command >>storage/logs/yourcommand.log 2>&1 &
```

There is one important thing only. FIRST COMMAND MUST BE "nohup", second command must be "forever" and "-c" parameter is forever's param, "2>&1 &" area is for "nohup". After running this line then you can logout from your terminal, relogin and run "forever restartall" voilaa... You can restart and you can be sure that if script halts then forever will restart it.

I <3 forever

Comment: does this also re-direct stderr? I want to direct everything, whether it is an error or output to a single source.

Answer (score 0):

To send the output of a nohup command to a custom file name, you can use the redirection operator `>` to specify the file name. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open your terminal or command prompt.
2. Run the `nohup` command followed by the command you want to execute, and redirect the output to the desired file name using the `>` operator. For example:

```
   nohup your-command > custom-file-name.log &
```

Replace `your-command` with the actual command you want to execute in the background, and `custom-file-name.log` with the desired file name for the output log.

3. Press `Enter` to execute the command. The output of the command will be redirected to the specified file name.
4. You can now close the terminal or command prompt without stopping the execution of the command. The output will continue to be written to the specified file.

Note: If you want to append the output to an existing file instead of creating a new one, you can use `>>` instead of `>` in the redirection operator.