# Redirect nohup's stderr to nohup.out

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stderr, nohup

How do I run a command with `nohup` so that *both* the stdout and stderr are saved to `nohup.out`? By default only stdout is saved and stderr is discarded.

Comment: Try this


nohup 2>&1 Executable.exe

Comment: Aha that works! Sorry I can't accept your "trivial answer" (a silly feature of stackoverflow if you ask me).

Comment: Actually stdout goes to nohup.out by default and stderr is not redirected. Otherwise you'd need `1>&2`.

Comment: Yeah good point - I will correct the question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this

```
nohup 2>&1 Ex.exe &
```