# nohup command not working in chef resources

Tags: linux, bash, shell, chef-infra, nohup

I am trying to execute

```
>nohup.out
nohup ./example.sh &
```

which comes under my main.sh file. I am calling the main.sh from my bash resource in Chef. However, the STDERR is thrown when I run the chef-client. Shouldn't it go to nohup.out ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect nohup's stderr to nohup.out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820616/redirect-nohups-stderr-to-nohup-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [nohup manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup):

> If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null. If standard >output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if possible, >'$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise. If standard error is a terminal, redirect it >to standard output.

So to have stderr redirected to nohup.out you should first redirect it to stdout:

```
nohup 2>&1 ./example.sh &
```